# pass the value of "Rate<%=Cnt%>" to be updated in updateRate function

Tags: java, javascript

```
 <table width=100%>
  <tr>

   <td id="show1" class="centerNoBorder">&nbsp;<input type="button" name="upd_rate" value="Update Rate" onclick="showEdit(1)"></td>
```

```
   <td id="show2" style="display:none" class="centerNoBorder">&nbsp;<input type="button" name="upd_rate" value="Save" onclick=" updateRate(); showEdit(2)"></td>
```

<%=cDouble%>
            <%=rscDesc%>
            " name="rscUm<%=Cnt%>"><%=rscUm%>
            " name="rscQty<%=Cnt%>"><%=rscQty%>
            <%if (rscDesc != null);
         {Cnt++; }

```
     System.out.println("Cnt_rscCnt" + rscCnt);%>
        <td class="leftAlign" valign=top id="rscRate"><div name="aEdit<%=Cnt%>" id="divRate<%=Cnt%>"><%=rscRate%></div><input type="text" id="Rate<%=Cnt%>" name="aEdit<%=Cnt%>" value="<%=rscRate %>" style="display:none"></td>
        <td class="leftAlign" valign=top id="rscCost"><div name="bEdit<%=Cnt%>" id="divAmt<%=Cnt%>"><%=calAmt%></div><input type="text"  id="Amt<%=Cnt%>" name="bEdit<%=Cnt%>" value="<%=calAmt %>" style="display:none"></td>
       </tr>
```

function updateRate()
{
alert ("updateRate"+ document.getElementById('flag').value);
for (var n=1; n<18; n++){
var aEdit=document.getElementById('aEdit'+n).value;
var bEdit=document.getElementById('bEdit'+n).value;
alert("HERE: " + document.getElementById('aEdit'+n).value);
}

public void uRate(int n) throws Exception
 {

System.out.println("b: "+n);
  String sqlUpdate="";
  MultiDBManager db7=new MultiDBManager(uif);
  sqlUpdate="update pklrsc set pr_prod_rate='showEdit"+n+"' and pr_ln_cst='showEditCost"+n+"' where pr_rsc_cde='rscDesc'";
  //"UPDATE pklrsc SET pr_prod_rate='Rate"+n+"' , pr_ln_cst='Amt"+n+"' WHERE pr_rsc_um= 'rscUm'"
  System.out.println("uRate");
  n++;
  db7.execUpdate(sqlUpdate); 
 }

Answer (score 0):

*re check sqlUpdate writing. you've got parsing error...

also- consider using concat instead of '+'*

```
concat('text1 with "some text2"', "text 3 and text 4", a_vartible, '">', a_name);
```